# Relationship properties are confused with nodes resulting in SyntaxError: Don't know how to compare that

Tags: neo4j

If I make the following Cypher query my results are as expected:

```
MATCH (:Keydata {key:"kgv"})<-[k:KEYDATA]-(s:Symbol) 
WHERE k.value>15.0 
RETURN k.value
```

- Nodes of label Keydata have properties {key: "some string"}
- Nodes of label Symbol have properties {key: "some string"}
- Relationships of label KEYDATA have properties {value: 123.45}

But if my Symbol nodes are matched before:

```
MATCH (s:Symbol) 
MATCH (:Keydata {key:"kgv"})<-[k:KEYDATA]-(s) 
WHERE k.value>15.0 
RETURN k.value
```

I get this Error: Don't know how to compare that. Left: "EVN" (String); Right: 15.0 (Double)

I am using Neo4j 2.0.1

Comment: That's strange. Are you sure all of your `[:KEYDATA].value` are numeric? Where does the string "EVN" come from? Can you create a small sample on http://console.neo4j.org that reproduces this?

Comment: EVN is a Symbol.key. If not all values where numeric the first query would also not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MATCH (s:Symbol),(:Keydata {key:"kgv"})<-[k:KEYDATA]-(s) 
WHERE k.value>15.0 
RETURN k.value
```

Is working. Seems like multiple MATCHES have a different meaning

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a `String` value with a double value, which is not possible. You have two options. Store the values in a different type or use Neo4j 2.1.0-M01 and use the `toFloat()` method. E.g.

```
WHERE toFloat(k.value)>15.0
```

Comment: toFloat is not available in Neo4j 2.0.1 https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/packaging/standalone/standalone-enterprise/src/main/distribution/text/enterprise/CHANGES.txt#L28